# Compare two data frame row by row in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to compare two data frame row by row such that if any mismatch found it prints in below formatted way.

Example:

```
data = [("James", "M", 60000), ("Michael", "M", 70000),
        ("Robert", None, 400000), ("Maria", "F", 500000),
        ("Jen", "", None),(None,None,None)]

columns = ["name", "gender", "salary"]
source_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=columns)
source_df.show() 
+-------+------+------+
|   name|gender|salary|
+-------+------+------+
|  James|     M| 60000|
|Michael|     M| 70000|
| Robert|  null|400000|
|  Maria|     F|500000|
|    Jen|      |  null|
|   null|  null|  null|
+-------+------+------+


data1 = [("Anurag", "M", 70000), ("Michael", "M", 70000),
         ("Sunil", None, 900000), ("Maria", "F", 500000),
         ("Jen", "", None),(None,None,None)]

columns = ["name_1", "gender_1", "salary_1"]
target_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=columns)
target_df.show() 

| name_1|gender_1|salary_1|
+-------+--------+--------+
| Anurag|       M|   70000|
|Michael|       M|   70000|
|  Sunil|    null|  900000|
|  Maria|       F|  500000|
|    Jen|        |    null|
|   null|    null|    null|
+-------+--------+--------+
```

So, here I have to iterate over row of 1st dataframe **James|M|60000** and compare with row of 2nd dataframe **Anurag|M|70000** and so on.. and print the output in formatted way if any mismatch found

```
eg :  
1st df: 'James|M|60000'
2nd df: 'Anurag|M|70000'
output: Mismatch: name-->James,name_1--> Anurag
                  salary-->60000, salary_1--> 70000..so on..
```

Please let me know if any other info required.

Very new to pyspark, so need your help. **Thanks in Advance for your help.**

The below code working fine for me.

````
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, monotonically_increasing_id, udf, col
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from os import truncate
import findspark
findspark.init()
findspark.find()
findspark.find()

def print_mismatch(row):
    output = ""
    for i in range(len(source_cols)):
        output += f"Row Index--> {row['id']}, "
        if row[source_cols[i]] != row[target_cols[i]]:
            output += f"{source_cols[i]}--> {row[source_cols[i]]}, {target_cols[i]}--> {row[target_cols[i]]} "
    return output



spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("SparkExample") \
    .getOrCreate()


data = [("James", "M", 60000), ("Michael", "M", 70000),
        ("Robert", None, 400000), ("Maria", "F", 500000),
        ("Jen", "", None), (None, None, None)]

columns = ["name", "gender", "salary"]
source_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=columns)
rdd_df = source_df.rdd.zipWithIndex()
source_df = rdd_df.toDF().select(col("_1.*"), col("_2").alias("id"))


data1 = [("Anurag", "M", 70000), ("Michael", "M", 70000),
         ("Sunil", None, 900000), ("Maria", "F", 500000),
         ("Jen", "", None), (None, None, None)]

columns = ["name_1", "gender_1", "salary_1"]
target_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=columns)
rdd_df = target_df.rdd.zipWithIndex()
target_df = rdd_df.toDF().select(col("_1.*"), col("_2").alias("id1"))

final_df = source_df.join(target_df, source_df.id == target_df.id1)
source_cols = source_df.columns
target_cols = target_df.columns
final_coulmn = source_cols + target_cols
df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema=final_df.schema)
for i in range(len(source_cols)):
    final = final_df.filter(
        final_df[f'{source_cols[i]}'] != final_df[f'{target_cols[i]}'])
    df = df.union(final)
    # final.collect()
final_df.show()

#df.show()
df_rdd = df.rdd
df_rdd.map(print_mismatch).collect() ```
````

Comment: This kind of process is not available on distributed systems. You can trick the system to perform it but it wont be performant.

Comment: As Steven mentioned, this is not possible in Spark in distributed mode. The order itself is altered when you do "spark.createDataFrame" . Consider using a single threaded process like Java for your operation.

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve the same as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, monotonically_increasing_id, udf, col


def print_mismatch(row):
    output = ""
    for i in range(len(source_cols)):
        if row[source_cols[i]] != row[target_cols[i]]:
            output += f"{source_cols[i]}--> {row[source_cols[i]]}, {target_cols[i]}--> {row[target_cols[i]]}"
    print(output)


spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("SparkExample") \
    .getOrCreate()

data = [("James", "M", 60000), ("Michael", "M", 70000),
        ("Robert", None, 400000), ("Maria", "F", 500000),
        ("Jen", "", None), (None, None, None)]

columns = ["name", "gender", "salary"]
source_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=columns)
rdd_df = source_df.rdd.zipWithIndex()
source_df = rdd_df.toDF().select(col("_1.*"), col("_2").alias("id"))
# source_df = source_df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
source_df.show()

data1 = [("Anurag", "M", 70000), ("Michael", "M", 70000),
         ("Sunil", None, 900000), ("Maria", "F", 500000),
         ("Jen", "", None), (None, None, None)]

columns = ["name_1", "gender_1", "salary_1"]
target_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=columns)
rdd_df = target_df.rdd.zipWithIndex()
target_df = rdd_df.toDF().select(col("_1.*"), col("_2").alias("id"))
# target_df = target_df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())

target_df.show()

final_df = source_df.join(target_df, source_df.id == target_df.id)
final_df.show()

source_cols = source_df.columns
target_cols = target_df.columns

final_df.foreach(lambda row: print_mismatch(row))
```

**name--> James, name_1--> Anurag salary--> 60000, salary_1--> 70000
name--> Robert, name_1--> Sunil salary--> 400000, salary_1--> 900000**

```
spark-submit --master local spark_combining_df.py
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEPY8.png)

Comment: That so much wrong using `monotonically_increasing_id` for that ... **The function is non-deterministic because its result depends on partition IDs.**

Comment: Thank you @Steven for the comment. Yes, I agree, `monotonically_increasing_id ` is non-deterministic. I have updated the answer with `zipWithIndex`, do you see any issue out of that, if not do you think that suffice the need/requirement.

Comment: Are you sure there is no shuffle step when you convert to rdd ? If so, zip won't work either.

Comment: Thank you so much @FelixKJose. One doubt what if I have more  than 300 columns. how will **print_mismatch()** function be modified as we cant manually write one by one column name over there. And also 'foreach' returns nothing. ** Thanks in Advance**

Comment: @Steven I dont see a reason for shuffle as there is no across partition operations. Do you see any reason for `shuffle`?

Comment: @anuragkumar I have updated the code to address your issue. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot @FelixKJose. I ran the code, everything runs fine but **final_df.foreach(print_mismatch)** is not returning anything. What mistake I am making here?

Comment: @anuragkumar `foreach` wont return anything instead it executes the `print_mismatch` function which will print the difference as expected.

Comment: @anuragkumar Could you let me know, if thats what you were looking for?

Comment: @FelixKJose-exactly same thing i am looking for. But it is not printing the difference. I checked in the local as well on cluster also.

Comment: @anuragkumar Did you copy the code as is, and run in your local? because you can see my screenshot of the output in the answer

Comment: And in the screenshot you can the printed output in Red

Comment: @FelixKJose-I exactly copied the same code and run in my local system. I am not getting how u got the output. i wish I could show you my screen.

Comment: @anuragkumar Could you put a simple print statement in the `print_mismatch`  function  and comment out the logic inside that and see if it prints.?

Comment: @FelixKJose- I tried with the same but it also not printing anything. after **print(final_df.foreach(print_mismatch))** it print **None** .

Comment: @anuragkumar Definitely `print(final_df.foreach(print_mismatch))` wont print anything. 
Could you update it as `final_df.foreach(lambda row: print_mismatch(row))`. Also you could see the screen shot when I run `spark-submit --master local spark_combining_df.py` the module with this code above.

Comment: @FelixKJose..Thanks a lot . I did few changes in your code and its working fine for me. I hope it works on large dataset as well. You can see changes in my post. Thank You.

Comment: @anuragkumar Awesome. If it works, could you accept the answer?

Comment: @FelixKJose. Yes